# Second page for a simple login web application in struts2 using JAVA not loading?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, web-applications, struts2

I have created following codes. But while running in apache tomcatv6.0 server secong page viz Welcome.jsp is not loading whereas first page ie Login.jsp is successfully loaded.Could anyone say what wrong with the coding??
I have created struts.xml inside src folder inside Java Resources folder.I'm using eclipse IDE.

StrutsDemo.java

```
package com.vishnu.struts;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class StrutsDemo extends ActionSupport{
    String username;
    String password;
    String returnString=null;

    public String execute()
    {
        if(getUsername().equals("abc")&&getPassword().equals("abc123"))
        {

            returnString=SUCCESS;

        }
        else {
            returnString=ERROR;
        }
        return returnString;


    }

    public String getUsername() {
           return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
   this.password = password;
}

}
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Still TRY TRY...</title>
</head>
<body>

<s:textfield name="username"/>
<s:password name="password" value="Password"/>
<s:submit method="execute" label="Click" action="doLogin"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Thank God...</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Gud to see you!!!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">


        <action name="doLogin" class="com.vishnu.struts.StrutsDemo" method="execute">

            <result name="success">/Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>STRUTS INTRO-VISHNU</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
```

Comment: can you post your stacktrace??

Comment: Could you tell me the error?

Comment: nothing error is being displayed..only thing is that second jsp page ie Welcome.jsp is not being loaded.

Comment: @subash i have never used any try-catch block.so no exception would be displayed over stacktrace..

Comment: @vishnuraj so what you get in browser.

Comment: @subash 1st login page with 2 text fields and a submit button are being displayed. but whenevr i provide required username and passwrd & click submit button it stays idle. next page is not being loaded!

Comment: you have no form. add form in your login.jsp

Comment: Where you have placed the JSP files? Is it under WebContent?

Comment: @Murugesh. yes i have attached it under WebContent.Anyway thanks and my problem is solved.problem was with form tag in Login.jsp.

Comment: fine, Accept the answer which has solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. you have no form then how your fields are post..

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Still TRY TRY...</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="doLogin">
  <s:textfield name="username"/>
  <s:password name="password" value="Password"/>
  <s:submit label="Click"/>
</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @vishnuraj enjoy **struts**

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project in IDE and the server too run again. May works..

Comment: hey Gokul I did several times and I have attached sufficient jar files. Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

use following code in your Login.jsp.,.

```
<form action="doLogin" method="POST">
<!--
Put all the content of Web Page here.,.
-->
</from>
```